# Does the gensim `Word2Vec()` constructor make a completely independent model?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm testing feeding gensim's Word2Vec different sentences with the same overall vocabulary to see if some sentences carry "better" information than others. My method to train Word2Vec looks like this

```
def encode_sentences(self, w2v_params, sentences):
    model = Word2Vec(sentences, **w2v_params)
    
    idx_order = torch.tensor([int(i) for i in model.wv.index2entity], dtype=torch.long)
    X = torch.zeros((idx_order.max()+1, w2v_params['size']), dtype=torch.float)
    
    # Put embeddings back in order
    X[idx_order] = torch.tensor(model.wv.vectors)    
    return X, y
```

What I'm hoping for here, is each time w2v runs, it starts with a fresh model and trains from scratch. However, I'm testing 3 kinds of sentences, so my test code looks like this:

```
def test(sentence):
    w2v = {'size': 128, 'sg': 1}
    X = encode_sentences(w2v, sentence)
    evaluate(X) # Basic cluster analysis stuff here

# s1, s2 and s3 are the 3 sets of sentences with the same vocabulary in different order/frequency
[print(test(s) for s in [s1, s2, s3]]
```

However, I noticed if I remove one of the test sets, and only test `s1` and `s2` (or any combination of 2 sets of the three), the overall quality of the clusterings decreases. If I go back into `encode_sentences` and add `del model` before the `return` call, the overall cluster quality also goes down but remains consistent no matter how many datasets are tested.

What gives? Is the constructor not actually building a fresh model each time with new weights? The docs and source code give no indication of this. I'm quite sure it isn't my evaluation method, as everything was fixed after the `del model` was added. I'm at a loss here... Are these runs actually independent, or is each call to `Word2Vec(foo, ...)` equivalent to retraining the previous model with `foo` as new data?

And before you ask, no `model` is nowhere outside of the scope of the `encode_sentence` variable; that's the only time that variable name is used in the whole program. Very odd.

#### Edit with more details

---

If it's important, I'm using Word2Vec to build node embeddings on a graph the way Node2Vec does with different walk strategies. These embeddings are then fed to a Logistic Regression model (`evaluate(X)`) and which calculates area under the roc.

Here is some sample output of the model before adding the `del model` call to the `encode_sentences` method averaged over 5 trials:

```
Random walks:   0.9153 (+/-) 0.002
Policy walks:   0.9125 (+/-) 0.005
E-greedy walks: 0.8489 (+/-) 0.011
```

Here is the same output with the only difference being `del model` in the encoding method:

```
Random walks:   0.8627 (+/-) 0.005
Policy walks:   0.8527 (+/-) 0.002
E-greedy walks: 0.8385 (+/-) 0.009
```

As you can see, in each case, the variance is very low (the +/- value is the standard error) but the difference between the two runs is almost a whole standard deviation. It seems odd that if each call to `Word2Vec` was truly independent that manually freeing the data structure would have such a large effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to the `Word2Vec()` constructor creates an all-new model.

However, runs are *not* completely deterministic under normal conditions, for a [variety of reasons](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/recipes-&-faq#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vecdoc2vecetc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism), so results quality for downstream evaluations (like your unshown clustering) will jitter from run-to-run.

If the variance in repeated runs with the same data is very large, there are probably other problems, such an oversized model prone to overfitting. (Stability from run-to-run can be one indicator that your process is sufficiently specified that the data and model choices are driving results, not the randomness used by the algorithm.)

If this explanation isn't satisfying, try adding more info to your question - such as the actual magnitude of your evaluation scores, in repeated runs, both with and without the changes that you conjecture are affecting results. (I suspect the variations from the steps you think are having effect will be no larger than variations from re-runs or different `seed` values.)

(More generally, `Word2Vec` is generally hungry for as much varies training data as possible; only if texts are *non-representative of the relevant domain* are they likely to result in a worse model. So I generally wouldn't expect being choosier about which subset of sentences is best to be an important technique, unless some of the sentences are total junk/noise, but of course there's always a change you'll find some effects in your particular data/goals.)

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have specified, I'm using this to run specialized node2vec tests with so the "sentences" are really random walks through a graph. I have added more detail to the question, as well as specific evaluation scores if any of that helps

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Those results *are* tighter for each alternative, but larger between the alternatives, than my theory alone seems to explain explain. But, if the results for 'Random walks' are equivalent to the prior 's1', it appears that you've shown that your `del model` line (presumably added just before `return X, y`) doesn't just affect *subsequent* results, but also the very 1st result – based on an `X` composed entirely before the `del`. If I'm reading that right, concentrating on understanding, & eliminating, that mystery should take priority over the multi-corpus run.

Comment: Being familiar withe the gensim code, I know the `Word2Vec` class isn't doing any fancy/non-intuitive reused of state, so I'm confident ruling that out - & would instead wonder about your unshown corpus-creation code, & unshown evaluation code, & possible non-intuitive operation of the `torch` routines. But even there, your `del model` should be nearly impossible to affect other code - even if its existence *was* a memory constraint for later steps, as a local variable the object was already eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: I would check especially if your way of composing corpuses could be altered by prior runs – consuming a non-repeatable iterator, failing to use all source files sometimes, etc. And similarly, if `evaluate(X)` might be caching old state, or more likely to (partially) fail in silent ways in some (low-memory?) conditions. (Maybe forking off heavyweight processes that sometimes fail in an uncaught way?) (What if you run exact same `evaluate(X)` many times on same `X`, is there any jitter/bias over time?) Run everything with more logging, & double-check assumptions (like `model` only local var).

Comment: I think you're right. I still haven't found it, but I'm pretty confident the problem is elsewhere in my code. Thanks!